# What should we give Cort Ammon for being the first WB user to break the 6-digit rep barrier?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

I think it's more than impressive that Cort Ammon broke the 6-digit rep barrier with a score of 100,169 as of this writing.  He broke the barrier sometime yesterday or this morning.  Stack Exchange probably doesn't throw parties for such feats, but I'm thinkin' it deserves some note.  WB's been around for a while now and it's taken quite some time and effort to climb that mountain.

Therefore, what would be an appropriate Kudo to give to Cort?  The accepted answer will be one that is most relevant to the practices and intent of Worldbuilding, reflects the culture and character of the site, and is the most outrageous.

Comment: [When last I checked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286330/why-doesnt-stack-exchange-pay-users-who-contribute-the-most/286332?noredirect=1#comment928979_286332), Stack Exchange has sent users swag packages when they reached 100k on a site. Cort may want to consider contacting SE, although I can ask about that. **Update:** I've just confirmed with a Community Manager that they still do this.

Comment: @HDE226868 They did contact me.  I'm sure it was an automated script that sent out the initial email, but it elicited a wonderful "They do care!" feeling =)

Comment: @CortAmmon Glad to hear it!

Comment: @CortAmmon, when you receive that swag package, please consider posting a photo here to help motivate the rest of us!

Comment: @CortAmmon congratulations!  What an accomplishment!

Comment: Hip-hip: huzzah!

Comment: Congratulations, @CortAmmon

Comment: We could get him an FBI investigation into possible vote rigging ? :-)  What can I say, Cort - Watergate left me very cynical.  Congrats.

Comment: Forced sabbatical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have the artist who drew the site's background draw a scene involving the subjects of Cort's **top 5/10 answers**, interpreted in the most creative (and possibly hilarious) way possible.

Or, a good-quality printed version of [one of the greatest answers ever posted on this site.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/40992/20154)

Comment: An inspired rendering of a young girl exploring how to cook an egg via magic would be so satisfying.  It'd totally fit with the site's decor too!

Comment: @CortAmmon Especially if it's a young girl forcing a demon to cook an egg for her!

Answer (score 16):

Naturally, we should do what happens in the Real World (TM) when someone shows promise of this sort --- give him **MORE & HARDER WORK** to do!

Comment: That actually is my gift to myself.  In the last 30k or so, I started justifying lower quality answers with "well, this will at least get me rep."  Now I have no excuse for shoddy work!

Comment: Right: only the toppest of quality output from you mister!

Answer (score 12):

A T-shirt with the background of the site in it.

Comment: Maybe the background for the back and the icon-planet with rings for the front. Or the other way around. (I am not a designer, though. Or somebody even capable of pretending I have artistic talent.)

Comment: Would a site background with a T-shirt in it suffice? We'd save on postage and we don't need to know his size...

Comment: The other side should have his reputation in large font at the top and then a list of all of his badges

Answer (score 6):

A copy of the site robot with a battery that can walk around his desk.

Answer (score 4):

@Cort Ammon is the [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) of Worldbuilding.

We should make an Ammon Facts post on Meta or Worldbuilding Meta, like the [Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) post.

And then we should tag it with a new Cort-Amon tag so when he answers it, he will get the tag badge.

Comment: Ooooh.  I really like this one as it's something we can actually do.

Comment: @JBH If you think that's a good idea, go ahead and then post the link here so that I can include it in my post (and also so I can start thinking of some good facts to write).

Comment: Cort Ammon is so good at world building this universe was created just so God could get advice from him on how to create the next one.

Comment: @Lio First there was God. And God created Cort Ammon. And God was about to create Earth, but Cort Ammon beat him to it and then started creating all of the other worlds. Now Cort Ammon is God.

Comment: First there was God and he said "let there be light" and Cort Ammon popped in and said "Hang on a moment, that's a bit handwavy, how about we set down some proper rules" and then there was Nuclear fusion (and therefore light).

Comment: @LioElbammalf I really like that one. (and therefore light)... And then Cort Ammon decided to create magic and then broke all of the rules.